# Convert .WMV to .MOV

Tags: file-formats, final-cut-pro-x, mac, windows, quicktime

A client gave me a file in Windows Media Video format. I need to edit it in Final Cut Pro X. The problem is that Final Cut Pro X can't read it. Neither can Apple Compressor. It has a Quicktime logo, suggesting that Quicktime can open it, but Quicktime cannot.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear alternate solutions, although my answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/).

It is a Wrapper for the ffmpeg package and does its job pretty well. Because of its easy UI.
You could also use ffmpeg directly via macports, but I think that Adapter is far easier to control.

Comment: 8 months later I faced the same issue on a new Mac. Adapter was so much simpler and easier than Flip4Mac. However, it only had an option to convert to .MP4, not .MOV, so I guess the answer to the original question is still Flip4Mac. However, +1 for solving the problem.

Comment: @NathanLucy Might be better, accepting this question.

Comment: @poor Yep. I confirmed Adapter works on my Mac running 10.10 Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is I didn't just overlook something. Transcoding .WMV to .MOV is a real problem. The bad news is that it cost me $29 to solve it. I purchased the "Player Pro" license for [Flip4Mac by Telestream](http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac/overview.htm) after reading this [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3526) by Apple.

Comment: Cheer up! There are many $600+ programs that can do that too.

Comment: Note that if you have a PC available, it is near trivial to go from WMV to MOV on a PC.  I guess it is a bit harder on a Mac though.